# How to monitor all executions of an executable over a time period

Tags: process, monitoring, executable

I know how to monitor a *process*. Commands like `top` and so forth can monitor the CPU time and memory usage for a given process instance.

But say I expect a given executable to be run several times in the next hour, and I want to measure how many times it is run and the CPU time it has consumed. What's a command for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
mv my-executable my-executable.bin
```

And create `my-executable` as a wrapper script that does:

```
#! /bin/bash -
{ time "$0.bin" "$@" 2>&3 3>&-; } 3>&2 2>> /tmp/times.log
```

The script could add more information to the log like the time it was started, by whom, the arguments it was passed...

[BSD process accounting, at least on Linux](http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/) does report CPU time (user + sys), though not in a cumulative way like `time` does (children processes CPU time is not accounted for the parent)